# Swithching mode function stuck with eachother

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 functions that do same thing but a bit different, it doesnt matter:

```
 public void easymode()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(easy());
        Clean();
        change_mode.SetActive(false);
        clickSource.PlayOneShot(clickSound, 0.5f);
    }


    public void normalmode()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(normal());
        Clean();
        change_mode.SetActive(false);
        clickSource.PlayOneShot(clickSound, 0.5f);
    }


    public void hardmode()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(hard());
        Clean();
        change_mode.SetActive(false);
        clickSource.PlayOneShot(clickSound, 0.5f);
    }
```

So I use StopAllCoroutines(), but it wont work. Why?

P.S. What clean() does:

```
 void Clean()
    {
        GameObject[] Trash = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Trash");
        foreach(GameObject item in Trash)
        {
            Destroy(item);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if that problem of my code or of unity itself. Tell me if code is fine, Im gonna search in unity project then

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Try explaining the expected results and the results you are getting.

Comment: what does `but it wont work` mean? What did you expect vs what happens instead? and how should we help here if we know nothing about the implementation of `easy`, `normal` and `hard` ...?

Comment: Well, I wanna get that when I use one coroutine, the another one should stop(So I get 1 instantiate, 2 or 3 with SINGLE COROUTINE), but I get that 2  or 3 work together so I get like 3 or even 6 instantiates that work at the same time